# Is it possible create a volume of CUPS from host server to docker container?

Tags: docker, printing, docker-volume, cups

I need to use to enable LP commmand inside docker container to print a PDF file, it would be necessary install cups inside docker container, but it is possible create a volume of that tools inside container?

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:15

WORKDIR /app/

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm --version

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm","run","serve"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ambiente_teste_project:
    build: .  
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: teste_container
    volumes:
      - /var/run/cups/:/var/run/cups/
```

After ran docker-compose, I realized that volume was being created successful, but `lp commmand does not exist`

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Looking around on npmjs.org suggests several printing libraries; will one of those work for your application?

Comment: yeah, I decided to use `lp command` I was using `print-js` but recently I've opened a 
question here about that library.